# Is there a problem with the python-docx lambda layer I've generated? Or is there something in my docx generator code?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-docx, aws-lambda-layers

I have generated a lambda layer for python-docx but when I run my lambda function the resulting docx has a unreadable content.

I've generated my layer using

```
pip install python-docx -t .
```

and zipping the content in a python.zip.

The docx part of my lambda function is a function that I call in my handler. The function within the handler is:

```
def create_docx_from_txt(filename, target_bucket, key):
upload_path = "/tmp/" + filename +".txt"

doc = Document()
with open(upload_path, 'r') as openfile:
    line = openfile.read()
    doc.add_paragraph(line)
    doc.save(upload_path.replace("txt","docx"))
    s3.upload_file(upload_path, target_bucket, key.replace(".json",".docx"))
```

I've run the same code localy in my machine and it works just fine.

Is it my layer that is not good or something in the docx code ?

Does anyone know where I can find a python-docx lambda layer so I can test it?

Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

**First** check your OS system since AWS Lambdas run in a Linux environment.

you can refer to this article for creating AWS Lambda Layers [hosting-your-ml-model-on-aws-lambdas-api-gateway-part-1](https://towardsdatascience.com/hosting-your-ml-model-on-aws-lambdas-api-gateway-part-1-9052e6b63b25) or look in this repo for already created layers [github repo - keithrozario](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers)

Comment: Thanks, @Agnij for the comment.
I've used a layer available at https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers but I still face the same problem.

Comment: Okay then you can try pulling down the image using Docker via the article I have given above, make sure to follow the folder structure and specify the python version.